# reactjs is using only the first item map() when calling state

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I'm looping through a list of items received from an api:

```
return (
  {jobs.map(
     (job: jobtype, index: number) => {
       return (
         <div className={'human-friendly'}>
           { job.StartedOn ?
             <div onClick={() => this.toggleBetweenDates(job.StartedOn)}> 
                  {this.state.date_to_show ? this.state.date_to_show : 
                    moment(job.StartedOn).fromNow()}</div>
             :
             'No date'
           }
             </div>
```

and this is my func:

```
   toggleBetweenDates(date: Date): void {
        if (this.state.show_original_date) {
            this.setState({
                date_to_show: date
            });
        } else {
            this.setState({
                date_to_show: moment(date).fromNow()
            });
        }
        let active: boolean = this.state.show_original_date
        this.setState({
            show_original_date: !active
        });
    }
```

Behaviour that I want: show formatted date using moment lib as default and then on click change it to original date, click again and you return to formatted date.

With the current setup, when I click it will change the dates for all items with the first item's date and I'm unsure why.

I'm storing the clicks as a boolean in state.show_original_date and the date in state.date_to_show

Comment: You can create new class component for one `job`, and put state there, so the state will be in each element of job

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are showing all dates as original, and when clicked, you want all the dates on a page to be updated to a formatted version of the date.

In your code, you are actually changing the date in the state - but you should not do this, instead, you should store a boolean (`datesFormatted`) which will tell you if you should render a formatted date or not.

Your toggle function would then look like this:

```
toggleDate() {
    // reverse the current state
    this.setState({
        datesFormatted: !this.state.datesFormatted,
    })
}
```

and your date rendering code would look like this:

```
{job.StartedOn ? (<span onClick={this.toggleDate}>{this.state.datesFormatted ? moment(job.StartedOn).fromNow() : job.StartedOn}</span>) : 'No date'}
```

If you want the dates to change individually, and not all at once - then you would want each date to contain it's own state. In this case, you need to create a child component which has it's own state.

```
class DateToggle extends Component {
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = {
            showFormatted: true,
        }
    }
    handleToggle = () => {
        this.setState({
            showFormatted: !this.state.showFormatted,
        })
    }
    render() {  
        let displayDate = this.props.date;
        if (this.state.showFormatted) {
            displayDate = moment(displayDate).fromNow()
        }
        return <span onClick={this.handleToggle}>{displayDate}</span>
    }
}
```

and then in your parent component, you can just pass your job date into it:

```
render() {
    return jobs.map((job, index) => (<DateToggle date={job.StartedOn} />));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As soon as you do this :

```
this.setState({
            date_to_show: date
        });
```

Rect components relying on this state variable will change. That's how state in react works. (Correct me if I am wrong).

You can maintain an array as state variable to solve this issue.

Change this line and try:

```
{ job.StartedOn ?
         <div onClick={() => this.toggleBetweenDates(job.StartedOn,index)}> 
              {this.state.date_to_show[index] ? this.state.date_to_show[index] : 
                moment(job.StartedOn).fromNow()}</div>
         :
         'No date'
       }
```

And inside the toggle date function :

```
toggleBetweenDates(date: Date,index:number): void {
   this.setState({
            date_to_show[index]: date
        });
```

Comment: thanks, mm, yes I expect all elements to change when this.setState is called, but I'm passing the job.StartedOn as a param, I don't understand why it's being overwritten. I agree your method with an array works but I hoped for a better solution

Comment: If the number of jobs/dates change while the page is being displayed, indexes would change and the wrong dates would be formatted / unformatted. Don't do this.